# why the return statement cannot find my int?

Tags: java

When I compile the code below, I get an error:

> "cannot find symbol - variable wayA"

Can someone please explain the reason?

```
private static int edit (String str1, String str2,int i, int j)
    {
        int len1=str1.length();
        int len2 = str2.length();
        if(len1==0 || len2==0)
            return 0;
        if(str1.charAt(0)==str2.charAt(0))
            return edit(str1.substring(1),str2.substring(1),i,j);
        int wayD =1+ edit

(str1.substring(1),str2,i,j);
        if(len2>len1)
        {
            int wayA = 1+edit(str1+str2.charAt(0),str2.substring(0),i,j);
        }
        return Math.min(wayD,wayA);
    // when i compile "cannot find symbol - variable wayA" why??
    }
```

Comment: `wayA` is defined inside an `if` block and is not visible outside of it.

Comment: @GalYakir please accept an answer, we spend time to answer you properly you can take 10sec to accept ;)

Comment: Please think about accept an answer, this is how a forum works, and a new user would be more attracted from accepted post than non-accepted post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable `wayA` is defined in the `scope` of the `if` block, so it does exists *only* between the brackets of the `if` , so you can't have access to it later

```
if(len2>len1){
   int wayA = 1 + edit(str1+str2.charAt(0),str2.substring(0),i,j);
}
return Math.min(wayD,wayA);
```

---

You need to define it *before* :

```
int wayA = 0;
if(len2>len1){
   wayA = 1 + edit(str1+str2.charAt(0),str2.substring(0),i,j);
}
return Math.min(wayD,wayA);
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiler cant find wayA because you declared it in the if block. Move the declaration of your int wayA out of that if block. Like this:

```
private static int edit (String str1, String str2,int i, int j)
{
    int len1=str1.length();
    int len2 = str2.length();
    if(len1==0 || len2==0)
        return 0;
    if(str1.charAt(0)==str2.charAt(0))
        return edit(str1.substring(1),str2.substring(1),i,j);
    int wayD = 1 + edit(str1.substring(1),str2,i,j);
    int wayA = 0;
    if(len2>len1)
    {
        wayA = 1+edit(str1+str2.charAt(0),str2.substring(0),i,j);
    }
    return Math.min(wayD,wayA);
```